# How many objects are in here?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, objects

> Paul accuses her of being over cautious. ([thearchers.co.uk](http://www.thearchers.co.uk/en/catch-up))

‘of being over cautions’ is adverbial complement.

Is there one (direct) object – *her* – in the sentence, or two?

indirect – *her*, and direct – *of being over cautious*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In (traditional?) grammar, an indirect object is a noun or a pronoun, not a phrase. In "Paul accuses her of being over cautious." *her* is the direct object; "of being over cautious" is a prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I would say in my terminology "her" is a direct object and "of being over-cautious" is a genitive object. The verb construction is to accuse someone of something.

Of course, I know that the term genitive object is normally not used in English grammars. But for me it is the simplest and clearest term.